# Will This Solenoid Driver Circuit Draw Any Current When Control Input is Disconnected?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, current, solenoid

I'm working on a battery powered circuit board to drive a small solenoid motor, simple TIP120 as a voltage controlled switch grounding one of the motor terminals. I'm wondering whether or not I need to include a power switch, or if I can just power off the board by leaving the control input unconnected.

My question is this: will the following circuit draw any current when the control input is unconnected (transistor is off, because voltage is 0 at base)?

[image: Solenoid Driver Circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be some leakage through the TIP120.

There will be a small amount of leakage from collector to emitter, and some from collector to base (which will then go through the 100 kΩ resistor).

It may not be well specified.  A datasheet I am looking at for the TIP120/TIP122 shows about 0.5 mA from collector to emitter if Vcc is 30 V.  See page 2 [HERE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwigrbXEjLzqAhVFrZ4KHVYkC9YQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.onsemi.com%2Fpub%2FCollateral%2FTIP120-D.PDF&usg=AOvVaw3QZ_b76mswiDDokFB4h9Qj).

You can find something else to use with much lower leakage than a darlington switch.  Some opto-isolators, for example, could drop right in and be over an order of magnitude lower leakage.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. My variable supply doesn't show any current, but I figured there might be a small amount of leakage under the level that it can display.

Comment: Is there any specific opto-isolator component you would recommend I try out?

Comment: I can't really do that here (rules against product recommendations), but the output leakage is often well specified on those.  You will need to know your voltages and how much current the motor uses in your search.  "Solid state relay" is a useful search term as well as opto-isolator.

Comment: You can also look at MOSFETs instead of BJT darlingtons.  There is still some leakage, but probably on the order of µA.  You will have to decide how much leakage you can tolerate, if any.  With MOSFETs there is a trade off between Vth and max current to leakage.  Low leakage means higher Vth and lower max current.